# SQL GROUP BY Overlapping Date Range (Eloquent)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following assignments table:

Assignments:

| personnel_id | work_code_id | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-12-17 08:00:00 | 2021-12-18 08:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-12-17 08:00:00 | 2021-12-17 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-12-17 11:00:00 | 2021-12-18 08:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | 2021-12-18 08:00:00 | 2021-12-19 08:00:00 |
| 3 | 5 | 2021-12-19 08:00:00 | 2021-12-20 08:00:00 |

Work Codes:

| id | name | ignore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Test 2 | 0 |
| 3 | Test 3 | 1 |
| 4 | Test 4 | 0 |
| 5 | Test 5 | 0 |

Problem 1:

I am trying to retrieve all results where there is a duplicate personnel_id with overlapping date ranges. This table should only return personnel_id 2 as their date ranges overlap. personnel_id 3 does not overlap. I have the following query to return the duplicate personnel_ids which works correctly. How do I add on the date overlapping constraint?

Problem 1 Solution:

```
Assignment::query()
            ->select(['a.personnel_id', 'a.time_start', 'a.time_end', 'p.first_name', 'p.last_name', 'w.ignore_validation'])
            ->from('assignments', 'a')
            ->join('assignments as b', function (JoinClause $query) {
                $query->on('a.personnel_id', '=', 'b.personnel_id')
                    ->on('a.id', '>', 'b.id');
            })
            ->join('people as p', 'a.personnel_id', '=', 'p.id')
            ->join('work_codes as w', function (JoinClause $query) {
                $query->on('a.work_code_id', '=', 'w.id');
            })
            ->where(function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where(function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->whereColumn('a.time_start', '>=', 'b.time_start')
                        ->whereColumn('a.time_start', '<', 'b.time_end');
                })->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->whereColumn('a.time_end', '>', 'b.time_start')
                        ->whereColumn('a.time_end', '<=', 'b.time_end');
                });
            })
            ->where('w.ignore_validation', '!=', true)
            ->whereDate('a.time_start', '=', $this->date)
            ->get();
```

Problem 2: Next, I want to perform a join with the work codes table using the work_code_id and add a where statement to prevent results where ignore is set to 1. Essentially, if one of the overlapping results from the assignments table has a work code ID that has ignore_validation set to 1, then the result will not be returned.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b90553/6 is how you'd do it in pure SQL using a self-join but you're complicating things here a bit by the additional joins and group bys (which I think you can replace with eloquent relationships instead).

Comment: Great, this is what I’m looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I've add an update to Problem 2 with the following fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e8356/4

Comment: I added a second join on the work codes table. Does the job but seems inefficient. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7769a4/1

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to be asking multiple questions in a single post in SO. It might be good to clean up this question a bit to make it more concise for the specific problem originally posted and also post an answer answering it  with your solution and create a new question with the next problem (possibly linking to this one but ideally it should also have all the information required within it) again attempting to keep it clean and concise. This being said I'm not sure how much luck you'll get with people answering seeing how it's time off for large parts of the world.